# CAlayer optimization

Tags: ios, optimization, calayer

I am applying a layer to an UIImageView in this way:

```
CALayer * l = [image1 layer];
            [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [l setCornerRadius:6.0];
```

Since I have 100 images, i noticed that without this layer, the scrolling in the UIScrollView is much faster. How can I optimize this??

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UITableView` instead of a `UIScrollView`, if possible. That'll enhance scrolling speed dramatically.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Other options?